# Can you be detained for not paying for your hotel in Pretoria?

Tags: hotels, south-africa

If you can't pay for your hotel, can either the hotel or the police keep you from flying home until you DO pay?

Comment: Africa is a very big place so I'd suggest adding exactly what country you're interested in, but in general yes, you can be detained for not paying your hotel bill.  This is a worldwide thing.

Comment: In petroia , this person didn't expect to have to pay and their money is state side and this party has 500.00 to pay towards bill but that's all